# How to resolve content spoofing? if I added ?actionMessages="someString" in the URL end it will display on jsp page

Tags: javascript, java

My URL is: htttp://localhost:8080/projName/CreateUser.action?actionMessages="HI"

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then Hi is print on the JSP.

I wish to stop content spoofing through URL

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please post the relevant portion of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing request param with json parse or try to bind URI GET params with request header 
**HTML escape JSON values in an HTML context and read the data with JSON.parse**

[Refer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)